# Хук Wordpress для добавления css класса

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите, есть ли хук как добавить товару на WooCommerce свой css класс? Нужно добавить класс товарам на витрине и одиночному так, чтобы при обновлении WooС, класс не слетал.
У кнопок есть class="button product_type_external" нужно, чтобы был class="button product_type_external eModal-1" для выполнение попап-скрипта.
Почему-то при помощи js вопрос не решается. JS упорно не хочет видеть элемент, которому нужно добавить класс

Comment: У товара в карточке и на витрине множество полей. Куда именно надо добавить css? Покажите свой имеющийся html и желаемый. Добавьте пояснение к вопросу не картинкой, а текстом (кнопка "Править").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете редактировать WooC файлы с помощью переопределений. Создайте в Вашей теме каталог /woocommerce. Скопируйте файл в каталог Вашей темы , сохранив структуру файла, но удалить /templates/ подкаталог в структуре путей. Пример: Чтобы изменить уведомление о заказе админу, скопируйте: wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/admin-new-order.php в wp-content/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php